# which text control to use in flex mobile app so that color of it's substring can be changed?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, mobile

I am creating an searchbox for a tablet application. On entering any text the results appear below as a list. Now I want to change color of that part of the text that is there in searchbox.
So which text control would allow me to do that. I found that RichText is one such control but Adobe recommends not to use it for mobileDevices. 
Any suggestion how I can tackle this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [StyleableTextField](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/supportClasses/StyleableTextField.html) and change the colors of substrings using HTML.

I use this approach for the [Flextras AutoComplete](https://www.flextras.com/MobileComponents/Samples/MobileAutoComplete/) component, although I have only tested  Bold in the mobile version; it should support other colors.  Conceptually like this:

```
No Color <font color="#492C8F">Color</font>
```

Both TextInput and TextArea use StyleableTextField under the hood in the Mobile Skins.